# Correct use of passive voice in "His mobile phone is turned off"

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

The following sentence has written in the passive voice, but Grammarly took an error as a "Passive Misuse", I would like to know what the problem has it?

```
His mobile phone is turned off
```

According to the passive voice's form: `Subject+to be (conjugated)+ past participle + rest of sentence` It should be correct.

Comment: Ask yourself whether it denotes a state or an action?

Comment: @BillJ: Thank you. It is an action verb. Hence, I think the correct one should omit `is` or use `has` instead of `is`, but since the form says `to be (conjugated)`, I am confused.
What the meaning of `conjugated`?

Comment: @BillJ: I have understood, thank you very much.

Comment: I made a typo, and have retyped by comment: The phone is in a state of being turned off. It doesn't denote an action, as it would in "His mobile phone is turned off every day (by him)". Can you see the difference between the dynamic and stative uses of "turned off"?

Comment: @BillJ: According to the usage of "to be" I had understood your meaning. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Active voice* is when a subject does an action to an object, for example:

> He turned off the mobile phone.

*Passive voice* is when the object and action take precedence over the subject, for example:

> The mobile phone was turned off by him.

Your sentence doesn't have a grammatical subject, because it doesn't say *who* turned off the phone. Just because it is "his" phone doesn't mean it can't be turned off by somebody else. It is neither in the passive, nor active voice.